# Flutter - grey widget area, but only for some users

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-html

I have a flutter web application that is running hosted on Firebase.

The application itself runs perfectly for 99% of the users but for some of them, a certain widget area appears grey like below:

[image]

The area in question is the Container at the top of the Column. A weird anecdote is that it mainly appears to happen to users running on a Linux machine.

The UI build is as follows:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
      child: ResponsiveBuilder(
          builder: (context, sizingInformation) => Scaffold(
                drawer: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType ==
                        DeviceScreenType.mobile
                    ? NavigationDrawer()
                    : null,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                body: Scrollbar(
                  child: 
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 1600,
                          height: 600,
                          child:
                        Scrollbar(
                          child: 
                          SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: widgetList
                          ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 50),
                          child: ComparativeArea(
                              key: UniqueKey(),
                              userList: userList,
                              mousaiUser: mousaiUser),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                 ),
             ),
        )),
    );
  }
```

Is there an obvious reason why this is occurring? I have tried adjusting the Container height and width as well as wrapping it in an Expanded() widget but the same thing happens (for about 2 of 100 users).

Comment: Do not use expanded unless it's inside a column or row, this might cause the error. Also the reason might be the :null condition in your responsive builder. Grey items mean render flex errors or null check operators used on null values most likely, and only in release builds. In debugging, it'd be a red screen, you know it.

Comment: Without knowing what the error actually is, It's hard to understand why that's happening,so it'd be hlpful if you could post the image of the error while in DEBUG mode

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recreate the issue. It seems to only be happening for a very small amount of users. I can't recreate the issue at all personally.

Comment: try to add ErrorWidget.builder in main(), then log it or send it to log handler / reporter to debug